# Sum of a random number of non-identically distributed random variables

Tags: convergence-divergence, summation, random-variables

> Let $X_1, X_2, ..., X_n$ be independent random variables. $E[X_k] = m^k$, where $m \neq 1, k = 1,2,...$. Let $N \in Po(\lambda)$ and independent of the variables. Set $S_0 =0$ and $S_N = X_1 + X_2+...+X_N$. Show that $E[S_N]=\frac{m}{m-1}(e^{\lambda(m-1)}-1)$

**My attempt:**

- From $E[X_k]=m^k$ it follows that $X_k\in Po(m^k)$.
- If $X_{i:n}$ where IID, I would use the classic formula for sums of random number of random variables: $g_{S_N}(t) = g_N(g_X(t))$. But this is not the case.
- I read this article without luck: https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0411298v1.pdf

**Any ideas for how I should go about solving this question?**

Comment: Shouldn't $S_N=X_1+X_2+...+X_{N-1}+X_N$? You have $X_3$ where $X_N$ should be.

Answer (score 1):

Condition on the value of $N$.

$$E[S_N] = \sum_{n=0}^\infty E[S_N|N=n]P(N=n) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=1}^n m^k\right) e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!} = e^{-\lambda}\sum_{n=0}^\infty m\frac{m^n-1}{m-1}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}$$

which simplifies to

$$e^{-\lambda}\frac{m}{m-1}(e^{\lambda m} - e^\lambda) = \frac{m}{m-1}(e^{\lambda(m-1)}-1)$$